# Temperature distribution in an infinite cylinder

Tags: partial-differential-equations

the Problem
An infinite Cylindrical:
$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial t} =2-3r+\nabla^2T$$
B.C/I.C:
$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial r}(1,\theta,t)=0$$
$$T(r,\theta,0) =1-3r^2+2r^3$$
Hint: Assume axial symmetry to simplify derivations

1. Well as i see the problem is Z axis independent, can i assume that from the fact  the cylindrical is infinite long? the hint?
2. Is $\theta$ is variable which need to be considered?
   in cylinder which subjected to wind or any natural convection, which perpendicular to the cylinder surface, this is the case because, with different angle, there is temp variation. Here i don't see it happening.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Consider the definition of $\nabla^2$ in terms of cylindrical coordinates and simplify the PDE based on the symmetry of the problem.

See here for the Laplacian in cylindrical coordinates.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator